# Mysql WHERE condition for (is not and is) in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with `remote_id` and `company_id` and much more rows.
Important part for me is to filter out where `remote_id = 1234 AND compnay_id = 1`
Like:

```
select * 
from `my_table` 
where (`remote_id` != 1234 and `company_id` = 1) 
AND `status` = 1 
and `amount` = 150
```

But this will return me only the results of `company_id = 1`  What i want is just to filter out the one record where `remote_id = 123 AND company_id = 1`

Comment: I don't understand: you filter on a `company_id` but you don't want to see only the result of this `company_id`??

Comment: i don't want to see results of remote_id:1234 AND company_id:1. Only if this two macth. Like a customer from company X. I want to see all records but not the one from company x with customer_id 1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your formulation you want `or` not `and` and to fix the second condition:

```
select *
from `my_table`
where (`remote_id` <> 1234 or `company_id` <> 1) and
      `status` = 1 and
      `amount` = 150;
```

However, you might prefer `not`:

```
select *
from `my_table`
where not (`remote_id` = 1234 and `company_id` = 1) and
      `status` = 1 and
      `amount` = 150;
```

Both of these (and your attempt) filter out `NULL` values.  If you don't want that behavior, use the `NULL`-safe comparison:

```
select *
from `my_table`
where not (`remote_id` <=> 1234 and `company_id` <=> 1) and
      `status` = 1 and
      `amount` = 150;
```

Comment: I could give myself a slap now. Thank you!!!